# Use Cloud Deployment Manager to define a Container-Optimized OS instance template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I use [google deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs?hl=fr) to create:

- an instance template
- an instance group manager
- an autoscaler

This works like a charm (I used this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/create-advanced-deployment?hl=fr)). However, I fail to define an instance template that runs a docker container (fwiw: the google cloud web console looks as [that](https://gyazo.com/99f16fc1d45f7b292a9330f0177ad252) when one creates such an instance template).

I tried several things (some might be dumb):

1. Take a look at the description of the working instance template and try to reproduce it.

   - use command `gcloud compute instance-templates describe <working-template>` to get an extensive definition of the working instance template
   - Define an instance template that matches the working instance template
   - Do a test deploy
   - SSH into spawned instance, confirm that target image is not pulled
2. Do not use [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes) (aka. copy [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/container_igm/python) )

   - In the [yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/common/container_manifest.yaml) replace `spec containers image` by my gcr.io hosted docker image.
   - Do a test deploy.
   - SSH into spawned instance, confirm that target image is not pulled.
3. Confirm that something is wrong with previous approaches: get the `gcloud` [console util command](https://gyazo.com/fc694c4641fddcf5a17b50ce7f618b79), duplicate the working instance template. Update the deployment so that the instance group uses this manually copied instance template.

   - Do a test deploy.
   - SSH into spawned instance, confirm that target image is not pulled.
4. Confirm that the google deployment manager is not messing around.

   - Update the deployment so that the instance group uses the working instance template.
   - Do a test deploy.
   - SSH into spawned instance, confirm all works as expected.

Am I going in the wrong direction here ?

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/Fkawala/dae8d24fefca75e7e9596bb6a711630a) contains sources for attempt #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with Container-Optimized OS I defined a template with a metadata "user-data" that contains a "cloud-config" file that creates a systemd service that runs the expected container.

I published the result on [gist](https://gist.github.com/Fkawala/87a8522c724995023314a46a651fe9d1), to make it work you'll have to (a) specify the `dockerImage` in the `deploy.yaml` file and (b) if you need special scopes update set them in `instance_template.py` along with your developer.gserviceaccount.com account.

Hope it helps.